# LRU Cache with a static variable for garbage value

Tags: c++, c++11, cache, stl

I have tried to implement a Least Recently Used cache with only C++ STL containers. The main thing that I keep asking my self the static variable called `garbage_val`. Is it a good practice to have such a `static` variable just for garbage values?

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
class LRU_Cache
{
struct Node
{
    Key k;
    Value v;
};

public:
static Value garbage_val;

LRU_Cache(unsigned int capacity)
{
    capacity_ = capacity;
}

Value get(Key key)
{
    auto node = cache_.find(key);

    if(node == cache_.end())
    {
        return garbage_val;
    }

    Value val = (*(node->second)).v;
    recentlyList_.erase(node->second);

    Node n; n.v = val; n.k = key;

    recentlyList_.push_back(n);
    cache_[key] = --recentlyList_.end();

    return val;
}

void set(Key key, Value val)
{
    auto node = cache_.find(key);

    if(node != cache_.end())
    {
        recentlyList_.erase(node->second);
    }
    else
    {
        evict_if_needed();
    }

    Node n; n.v = val; n.k = key;
    recentlyList_.push_back(n);
    cache_[key] = --recentlyList_.end();
}

void evict_if_needed()
{
    if(cache_.size() >= capacity_)
    {
        auto node = cache_.find(recentlyList_.begin()->k);
        recentlyList_.pop_front();
        cache_.erase(node);
    }
}

virtual ~LRU_Cache(void)
{
}

void print()
{
    std::cout << "Objects in Memory:" << std::endl;
    for(auto& c : cache_)
    {
        std::cout << "(" << c.first << "," << (*(c.second)).v << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Recently used:" << std::endl;
    for(auto& r : recentlyList_)
    {
        std::cout << "(" << r.k << "," << r.v << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
private:
LRU_Cache(void){}

std::unordered_map<Key, typename std::list<Node>::iterator> cache_;
std::list<Node> recentlyList_;
unsigned int capacity_;
};
template<typename Key,typename Value> Value LRU_Cache<Key,Value> ::garbage_val;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to have such a static variable just for garbage values?

Maybe not:

- `garbage_val` is a `Value`, so if you return it, then the caller doesn't know whether the `get` succeeded.
- If `garbage_val` is supposed to be a magic number (an impossible `Value`), different users of the class might want different magic numbers ... so why isn't `garbage_val` an instance member instead of a static member?
- Normally container classes expect the caller to check that `iterator != end()` before dereferencing the iterator.

Instead, the following methods might be appropriate:

```
// throws an exception if key does exist.
Value get(Key key) { ... }
// tests whether key exists: use this before calling get.
bool contains(Key key) { ... }
// return true and initializes value iff key exists.
// if key doesn't exist then valueOut is not initialized. 
bool tryGet(Key key, Value& valueOut) { ... }
```